# Как перебрать циклом массив для поиска совпадений?

Tags: java, android, массивы, циклы

Пишу свою первую игру по типу три в ряд! В процессе создания игры сделал следующее:

- добавил `GridView`;
- с помощью класса ImageAdapter разместил массив изображений на `GridView`;

Вот код класса ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

   public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
       mContext = c;
}

   public int getCount() {
       return mThumbIds.length;
}

   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return mThumbIds[position];
}

   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
}

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null) {

        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

          } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

   public Integer[] mThumbIds = {

        R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem5, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem5, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2,
        R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem5, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem4,
        R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem3,
        R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4,
        R.drawable.gem5, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2,

        R.drawable.gem5, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4,
        R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem5, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4,
        R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2,
        R.drawable.gem2, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4,
        R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem1, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem3, R.drawable.gem4, R.drawable.gem2
   };


   }
```

Это xml код GridView :

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grid"
        android:columnWidth="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
</GridView>
```

Это код класса GameActivity:

```
 public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

 private Button btn;


{
    this.btn = btn;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    final ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(this);

    final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemListener = new 
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            if (true) {
                btn.setText("РАБОТАЕТ");

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.drawable.gem1:
                       // parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                       //  parent.getSelectedView();
                       //  parent.getOnItemClickListener();
                        break;
                }
            }
            }
    };
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener); 
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

`Button` я добавил для проверки реагирует ли изображение на нажатие. Когда нажимаю на камень на игровом поле – меняется надпись на кнопке. Вся моя проблема в том, что я не знаю как пройтись циклом по массиву `mThumbIds` чтобы проверять на совпадения элементы массива. Я так понимаю что проверку на совпадения нужно делать по горизонтали и вертикали и что за меня никто этот код писать не будет. Мои познания еще малы, поэтому прошу опытных разработчиков помочь мне понять как это работает!

Хочу сделать стандартную логику три в ряд, а именно:

- чтобы камни передвигались и контактировали друг с другом (если рядом камень не того типа нужно чтобы первый камень вернулся назад );
- если 3 одинаковых камня - они исчезают, на их место падают новые ;
- если 4 од. камня - то появляется камень другого типа , который уничтожает ряд по вертикали или горизонтали;
- если 5 од. камней - появляется камень, который уничтожает все камни выбранного типа на игровом поле.

Реализовать я хочу все сам. Мне просто нужен толчек хотя-бы по первым двум пунктам. Дальше я сам. 
Искренне Вас прошу помочь новичку.